# Using MediaInfo to read subtitles infos with Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch, media-info

According to the answer in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/991201/700322), about MediaInfo to read subtitles.

```
MediaInfo.exe "--Output=Text;%ID%: %Format%$if(%Language/String%, SUBTiTLE: .....%Language/String%)\r\n" File.mkv
```

thanks slhck, I've done this.
(Sorry for my English.)

The target is I want to get the info texts (ID, Format & Language) of all subtitles in all video files (*.m*) in folder.

`` SET informParams=%%ID%%+%%Format%%+%%Language/String%%
FOR /F "delims=" %%Z IN ('DIR /B /S "*.m*"') DO (
echo ....................................................................
echo %%Z&echo.
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%B IN (`mediainfocli.exe "--Inform=Text;%informParams%\r\n" "%%Z"`) DO (
echo %%B
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=+" %%C IN ("%%B") DO (
echo        ID: %%C
echo        Format: %%D
echo        Lang:   %%E
echo.
)
)
) ``

The output be like....

`....................................................................
F:\MOVIES\The Long Ships.mkv
4+PGS+English
ID:     4
Format: PGS
Lang:   English
....................................................................
F:\MOVIES\The Vikings.mkv
4+UTF-8+English
ID:     4
Format: UTF-8
Lang:   English
5+VobSub+Thai
ID:     5
Format: VobSub
Lang:   Thai
6+PGS+Thai
ID:     6
Format: PGS
Lang:   Thai
7+PGS+Thai
ID:     7
Format: PGS
Lang:   Thai
8+VobSub+Thai
ID:     8
Format: VobSub
Lang:   Thai`

Could you please tell me how to use this in batch file? (Windows)

Comment: This is not a PM, there is no such feature on Stack Exchange. Anyway, have you tried to write a loop? There is plenty of information out there on batch scripting.

Comment: PM lol. i'm new with this kind of forum.

yes i've tried using loop, like this....

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%B IN ('MediaInfo.exe --Inform="Text;%ID%: %Format%$if(%Language/String%, SUBTiTLE: .............. %Language/String%)\r\n" "%%Z"') DO (
    for /f "xxx xxx=" %%C in %%B DO(
        .....
    )
)

I think my problem is using "tokens and delims".

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code youve tried. Also show any errors you get. Make sure that you use proper formatting (see the code button in the editor). Thanks