# Apply MediaInfo batch for multiple files

Tags: windows-10, batch, media-info

I frequently use the following command:

```
MediaInfo.exe "--Output=Text;%ID%: %Format%$if(%Language/String%, SUBTiTLE: .............. %Language/String%)\r\n" File.mkv
```

This will output the subtitle streams of a video vile in the format:

```
5: UTF-8
6: VobSub SUBTiTLE: .............. French
7: VobSub SUBTiTLE: .............. English
8: VobSub SUBTiTLE: .............. French
```

Source: [Get subtitle list using mediainfo in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/990639/get-subtitle-list-using-mediainfo-in-windows)

However I would like to run the same command for all files in a folder.

I have tried

```
for %%a in (%*) do  (
MediaInfo.exe "--Output=Text;%ID%: %Format%$if(%Language/String%, SUBTiTLE: .............. %Language/String%)\r\n"
)
```

but it does not seem to work and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

In your test code I don't see "%%a" (the file name to use) in the MediaInfo call and also I don't see "%" escaped ("%%") in the MediaInfo parameters (without percentage escaping, MediaInfo receives empty strings due to "%" converted by the batch processor).

I successfully did what you try to do with:

```
>dir test
06/09/2017  14:02         2 869 248 MOV001 - Copy.MOD
06/09/2017  14:02         2 869 248 MOV001.MOD

>more a.bat
@echo off
for %%f in (%*) do (
MediaInfo.exe "--Output=General;%%FileName%%, %%Format%%" "%%f"
)

>MediaInfo.exe "--Output=General;%FileName%, %Format%\r\n" test\*
MOV001 - Copy, MPEG-PS
MOV001, MPEG-PS

a.bat test\*.*
MOV001 - Copy, MPEG-PS
MOV001, MPEG-PS
```

Comment: Thanks but this batch file reruns nothing on my computer...